# NUnit 3 CollectionConstraint custom IComparer<T> not working

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

*Question*

**How can I correctly use a custom `IComparer<T>` with NUnit3 collection constraints for a collection containing a number of custom interface references?**

*What I have tried*

I have a class that returns an instance of `IEnumerable<IInterface>` where `IInterface` is defined as follows:

```
public interface IInterface 
{    
    string PropertyOne { get; }

    string PropertyTwo { get; }    
}
```

I am trying to use collection constraints from NUnit3 with a custom `IComparer<T>`, but it is not working. To create a mock object to test against,
 I'm using [Moq](https://github.com/moq). The test looks roughly like this:

```
[Test]
public void MyTest() 
{        
    var mockObject = new Mock<IInterface>();
    mockObject.Setup(x => x.PropertyOne).Returns("Foo");
    mockObject.Setup(x => x.PropertyTwo).Returns("Bar");

    var collection = myObject.Collection;

    Assert.That(collection, Contains.Item(mockObject).Using(this));
}
```

The test case is contained in a class that inherits from the following base class

```
public class TestBase : IComparer<IInterface> 
{
    public int Compare(IInterface one, IInterface two) { /* some code */ }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint on the above `Compare` method, I'm finding that NUnit is completely ignoring my comparer, chosing to use the `ToString()` implementation on the underlying object, despite the fact that it isn't exposed by the interface.

Comment: What is `IAssembly` in your example? How does it relate to `IInterface`?

Comment: @Charlie Sorry that was a mistake. I've edited it now.

Comment: @Ben Wainwright I think the problem is in this line Assert.That(collection, Contains.Item(mockObject).Using(this)) where mockObject is of Mock<IInterface> object instead of the IInterface. Could you change this to ...Contains.Item(mockObject.Object).Using(this)...

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how `Nunit3` is supposed to work with custom `IComparer<T>` together with `Constraints`. If custom comparer is provided `Nunit3` store it within the list of so called **external comparers**. Every `IComparer<T>` will be internally stored as an `EqualityAdapter`. Later on when at the comparison point it will try to cast `objects` to `T` in order to decide whether custom comparer should be used or not.

There we are with your example, you have a `ICollection<IInterface>` but the `Constraint` which you created uses `Mock<IInterface>`. Obviously `IInterface` cannot be compared with `Mock<IInterface>`.

Personally I found this misleading because the problem will popup in the runtime instead in compile time. The following examples will explain the problem:

**Wrong usage example**

```
//notice that Constraints is created for the int but IComparer<string> is used
List<string> strs = new List<string> {"1", "2", "3"};
Assert.That(strs, Contains.Item(5).Using((IComparer<string>) comparer));
```

**Right usage example**

```
//notice that Constraints is created for the string and IComparer<string> is used
List<string> strs = new List<string> {"1", "2", "3"};
Assert.That(strs, Contains.Item("5").Using((IComparer<string>) comparer));
```